# create a spring form through javascript and append in div

Tags: javascript, spring

what i am doing right now is appending a form created in javascript to the page. normal tag get appendend but when i try to append the spring form
tag it wont work is there any way i can accomplish it.the application is single page app.so the form are generated in javascript and appended in the html.

```
function createPage(){
 var htmlcontent="<div class='box-content'>"

                +"<form:form action='UserController/addUser' id='userAddForm' method='post' commandName='userObj'>"

                +"<div class='form-group'>"
                +"<label class='control-label'>First Name</label>"
                +"<form:input path='firstname' class='form-control'/>"
                +"</div>"
                +"</div>"
$("#content").html(htmlcontent);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't dynamically create spring forms with javascript.
You can create a spring form in your jsp which is compiled at server side and then transfered to your browser.

The server side needs to know which forms and input elements are managed to handle them.

Comment: Yup realized it but is there any way if possible to achieve it.